# Blockquote border on tumblr theme

Tags: html, css, css-float, border

This is the code for the link block:

```
            {block:Link}
        <div class="post link">
            <h2>
             <a href="{URL}" class="name">{Name}</a></h2>

            <div class="content">
                {block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}
                <span class="date">
                <a href="{Permalink}">{ShortMonth} {DayOfMonth}, {Year}
                </a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        {/block:Link}
```

What I'm trying to do is add a border-left of of 10px to block quotes. When I try to add this style to block quotes this happens:
[image]

The block quote border flows into the post title and I don't wish for this to happen, I want the border layout to stay within the content div.

I'm using this CSS at the moment:

```
            div div div blockquote {
            border-left: 10px solid red;
        }
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Just to clarify `<div class="post link">` is in another `div`.

Here is the tumblr: http://iamsomething-awesome.tumblr.com/

Comment: can you give us a link to your tumblr?

Comment: Yes, here http://iamsomething-awesome.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float: left;` from `div.post h2` rule and you got it:
[image: float: left issue on blockquote]

Firstly I check negative margins of `blockquote` itself and several parents(*elements* in further text) of it — and not found any negative margins.

Then I checked with non-standard values of *elements* for `display` property, but nothing special.

Then I searched for specified properties which changing float of layout, and first closely to blockquote element is `div.post.h2` which has `float` setted to `left`.

**Bingo!**

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks.
Do you mind letting me know how you figured it out?

Comment: @orange explanation added to post